# How to separate tuple of lists into 2 separate lists?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I wrote a function that takes a list and generates 2 new lists; 1 for strings and 1 for integers. It works but it returns the lists as a tuple. I would like for it to print the lists on separate lines, not in parentheses.

```py
# Make list
l = [1, 2, 3, "a", "b"]

# Declare function
def filter_list(l):
    filtered = []
    filtered2 = []
    
# Loop over each char in list to split by type
    for i in l:
        if type(i) == str:
            filtered.append(i)
        elif type(i) == int:
            filtered2.append(i)
    return filtered, filtered2

print(filter_list(l))
```

I get:

```py
(['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3])
```

but I want:

```py
['a', 'b']
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: `print(*filter_list(l), sep='\n')`

Comment: Your method can return only one value (buy yield multiple ones). That is why you get tuple including both your list.  You should handle printing separatly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to unpack the tuple:

```py
strings, numbers = filter_list(l)
print(strings)
print(numbers)
```

This outputs:

```py
['a', 'b']
[1, 2, 3]
```